# Interpretação do provérbio “quem faz filhos em mulher alheia perde-lhe o tempo e o feitio”

Tags: significado, proverbios

Meu pai me disse que meu avô costumava falar o seguinte provérbio:

> Quem faz filhos em mulher alheia, perde-lhe o tempo e o feitio.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o significado dele?

Comment: Pedro, bem-vindo ao site. Podes indicar onde é que encontraste esse provérbio?

Comment: Meu pai me disse que meu avô costumava falar esse provérbio. Pedro.

Comment: @Koba, tu és o Pedro desta pergunta? Eu até já tinha editado a tua pergunta incluindo a informação adicional no teu comentário (é bom a própria pergunta indicar donde é que conheces o provérbio), mas depois reparei que o comentário é do Koba e fiz "roll back", porque não tenho a certeza absoluta se és a mesma pessoa. Outra coisa, para eu ser notificado de comentários que me dirijas, inclui "@jacinto" (como eu fiz para ti; para o Pedro não foi necessário, porque o autor do post é sempre notificado).

Comment: Olá @jacinto. Sou o Pedro, eu, normalmente, utilizo esse site na board de química. Eu não tinha conseguido utilizar o meu perfil normal (@koba) aqui e acabei criando o outro. Entretanto, percebi que eu estava acessando o site de modo incorreto e por isso o acesso me estava sendo negado. Agora eu consegui utilizar meu perfil aqui. Obrigado pela resposta, um abraço.

Answer (score 10):

O significado não é nada o que eu estava à espera. Significa que quem faz melhoramentos em algo que não lhe pertence, não tira proveito deles. Por exemplo, pintas uma casa alugada e renovas o soalho, depois se tens de ir embora, o dono da casa é que beneficia do trabalho e despesa que tiveste. A frase aparece no [dicionário de Domingos Vieira de 1871](https://books.google.pt/books?id=6MdRAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA304&dq=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiezfLiy-P3AhVYt6QKHa5nCIsQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&f=false):

> **Alheio** […] *Fazer filhos em mulher* alheia, fazer bemfeitorias em propriedade de outrem.

A Grande Enciclopédia Portuguesa e Brasileira de 1936 diz:

> Fazer filhos em mulher alheia: trabalhar sem tirar proveito, que fica para outro.

O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei é de 1858, em que um indivíduo alega ser o legítimo proprietário de terras em que outro fez obras (grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> […] e nem a esperteza de se haver contra o direito levantado nas mesmas terras um engenho de esteios, e feito outras obras, o que foi em tempo devidamente embargado, pois que he bem sabido que **quem faz filhos em mulher alheia perde-lhe o feitio**, prejudica ditos titulos, e o reconhecimento judicial de pertencerem as referidas terras ao engenho Pintos […]
> [*Diário de Pernambuco*, 5 de abril de 1858](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=029033_03&pesq=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&pasta=ano%20185&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=9958)

Tal como neste caso, a maior parte dos exemplos mais antigos que encontrei são a propósito de obras em terras ou casas de outros:

> bem se lhe roía a alma por ter posto o corpinho durante tanto tempo a esmoitar aquele matagal e agora, depois da terra escolhida―que nem uma pedra lhe deixou no meio―acabou-se. **Isto de fazer filhos em mulher alheia, perde-se-lhe o tempo e o feitio**. Merda.
> [Luís de Carvalho e Oliveira, *Santofâmia*, 1962](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Ez8RAQAAIAAJ&q=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&dq=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkyZj31eP3AhUJCxoKHe3UCD84FBDoAXoECAgQAg)

Frequentemente, encontra-se simplesmente *fazer filhos em mulher alheia:*

> […] o rendeiro deseja prazos prolongados que lhe permitam reter a segunda renda diferencial obtida com a inversão de novos capitais: o proprietário deseja beneficiar-se dos melhoramentos que o rendeiro faz; êste evita fazê-lo por não estar disposto a “**fazer filhos em mulher alheia**”.
> [Álvaro Cunhal, *A questão agrária em Portugal*, 1968](https://books.google.pt/books?id=SmIQAQAAIAAJ&q=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&dq=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj8JCjv-P3AhU4QUEAHYXeBiIQ6AF6BAgCEAI)
>
> ― É verdade, ó Duartinho: os meu sinceros parabens: ¡mandaste abrir uma sacada na casa onde moras, e pôr um belo portão de ferro!... Não te devia ficar nada barato.
> ― ¡Tu estás a troçar-me, com toda a certeza! Era o que me faltava: **fazer filhos em mulher alheia**! ... Isso tudo, foi mandado fazer pelo meu senhorio , meu velho.
> [José da Fonseca Lebre, *Locuções e modos de dizer na Província da Beira Alta*, 1924](https://books.google.pt/books?id=H30QAQAAIAAJ&q=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&dq=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik7eyrxuP3AhXK1qQKHSTLAZw4ChDoAXoECAcQAg) mais [segundo excerto para completar](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dRAprA5wRtIC&q=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&dq=%22filhos%20em%20mulher%20alheia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBifWlyeP3AhXIGewKHU_UCzQ4FBDoAXoECAcQAg)

Comment: Muito interessante.  Não conhecia.

Comment: @Centaurus, já somos dois... :)